# How to get specific info from an array expressed in a string?

Tags: php, json

When I put this http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php in url bar it give me an array in this format how can i extract information from it?

```
{"country_name":"PAKISTAN","country_code":"PK","city":"Lahore","ip":"180.178.147.131"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP

```
<?php
$jsonstringfromyourapi='{"country_name":"PAKISTAN","country_code":"PK","city":"Lahore","ip":"180.178.147.131"}';
$arr=json_decode($jsonstringfromyourapi,1);

foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
echo "$k = $v<br>";
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/101878)